# Draw and rotate the text along z axis in opengl/opentk

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, coordinate-transformation

I need to draw string/text in opengl/opentk and then rotate it along z axis from the center of text itself.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
void drawstring(string text, Font font, float fontsize, SolidBrush brush, float x, float y)
{
    if (text == null || text == "")
        return;
    /*
    OpenTK.Graphics.Begin(); 
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PushMatrix(); 
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Translate(x, y, 0);
    printer.Print(text, font, c); 
    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PopMatrix(); printer.End();
    */

    float maxy = 1;

    foreach (char cha in text)
    {
        int charno = (int)cha;
        int charid = charno ^ (int)(fontsize * 1000) ^ brush.Color.ToArgb();

        if (!charDict.ContainsKey(charid))
        {
            charDict[charid] = new character()
            {
                bitmap = new Bitmap(128, 128, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb),
                size = (int)fontsize
            };

            charDict[charid].bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);

            //charbitmaptexid

            float maxx = this.Width / 150; // for space

            // create bitmap
            using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(charDict[charid].bitmap))
            {
                var pth = new GraphicsPath();

                if (text != null)
                    pth.AddString(cha + "", font.FontFamily, 0, fontsize + 5, new Point((int)0, (int)0),
                        StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

                charDict[charid].pth = pth;

                gfx.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                gfx.DrawPath(this._p, pth);

                //Draw the face

                gfx.FillPath(brush, pth);

                if (pth.PointCount > 0)
                {
                    foreach (PointF pnt in pth.PathPoints)
                    {
                        if (pnt.X > maxx)
                            maxx = pnt.X;

                        if (pnt.Y > maxy)
                            maxy = pnt.Y;
                    }
                }
            }

            charDict[charid].width = (int)(maxx + 2);

            //charbitmaps[charid] = charbitmaps[charid].Clone(new RectangleF(0, 0, maxx + 2, maxy + 2), charbitmaps[charid].PixelFormat);

            //charbitmaps[charno * (int)fontsize].Save(charno + " " + (int)fontsize + ".png");

            // create texture
            int textureId;
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexEnv(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureEnvTarget.TextureEnv, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureEnvParameter.TextureEnvMode,
                (float)TextureEnvModeCombine.Replace); //Important, or wrong color on some computers

            Bitmap bitmap = charDict[charid].bitmap;
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.GenTextures(1, out textureId);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindTexture(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId);

            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexImage2D(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
                OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexParameter(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter,
                (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexParameter(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter,
                (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

            //    OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)All.Nearest);
            //OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.Nearest);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Flush();
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

            charDict[charid].gltextureid = textureId;
        }

        float scale = 1.0f;

        // dont draw spaces
        if (cha != ' ')
        {
            /*
            TranslateTransform(x, y);
            DrawPath(this._p, charDict[charid].pth);

            //Draw the face

            FillPath(brush, charDict[charid].pth);

            TranslateTransform(-x, -y);
            */
            //OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            //OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BlendFunc(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Enable(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.EnableCap.Texture2D);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.BindTexture(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget.Texture2D, charDict[charid].gltextureid);

            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Begin(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x, y);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + charDict[charid].bitmap.Width * scale, y);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + charDict[charid].bitmap.Width * scale, y + charDict[charid].bitmap.Height * scale);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + 0, y + charDict[charid].bitmap.Height * scale);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.End();

            //OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Disable(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.EnableCap.Texture2D);
        }

        x += charDict[charid].width * scale;
    }
}
```

I am able to write text with this but unable to rotate. And also for some characters it is taking too much space which causes a gap between texts.

Comment: I have edited the question with my current code. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to write text with this but unable to rotate

You have to apply a rotation matrix to the model view matrix.

Choose the model view matrix stack [`glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).

Push the current matrix on the matrix stack [`glPushMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml).

Multiply the current matrix by a rotation matrix around the z-axis [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml)

```
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.MatrixMode(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.MatrixMode.ModelView);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PushMatrix();
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Rotated( angle_degree, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Begin(OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x, y);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + charDict[charid].bitmap.Width * scale, y);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + charDict[charid].bitmap.Width * scale, y + charDict[charid].bitmap.Height * scale);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Vertex2(x + 0, y + charDict[charid].bitmap.Height * scale);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.End();

OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PopMatrix();
```

Note, if you want to "reset" the current matrix, then this can be done by 
[`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml).

---

If you want to change the rotation point, then you have to translate to the rotation point, then rotate and finally translated back from the rotation point.
The translation can be done by [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml). Possibly `TranslateTransform` can be used in your case, but since I can't "see" what it is doing, I can't be sure.

```
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PushMatrix();
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Translate( rotate_center_x, rotate_center_y, 0.0);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Rotated( angle_degree, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.Translate( -rotate_center_x, -rotate_center_y, 0.0);

.....

OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.PopMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying firstly. I am totally new to this OpenGL library. If you could let me know where I have to add these lines specifically, that would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: I tried this. What it does is it rotates the panel where I am writing these texts. I can guess I am missing a GL.Translate(x, y, z) statement, but I am not sure what should I pass on as coordinates(x, y). Any idea?